# Python OpenCV return black image form external camera

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I'm trying to change the input source for OpenCV to an external camera. It opens a dialog asking me to select a capture source and when I select the external USB camera (C170) it only shows a black screen for the capture.

1. The code works well with an internal camera - cv2.VideoCapture(0).
2. I've checked that this camera - (31), is working, and it worked well when was called from processing.
3. The entire code worked well on a Macbook with an external camera.

   ```
   class Camera:
       def __init__(self, src=31):
           self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(31)
           self.grabbed, self.frame = self.stream.read()
           t = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
           t.daemon = True
           t.start()

       def update(self):
           while True:
               self.grabbed, frame = self.stream.read()
               self.frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

       def read(self):
           return self.frame

       def stop(self):
           self.stream.release()
   ```

I expect to see the image from the webcam.
I don't see any error messages, just the dialog, and a black capture screen.

Answer (score 0):

Going to the device manager and disabling my built-in camera did the trick.